# JPQL not giving results

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0, spring-data

In my application I am hitting DB using JPA (With Hibernate as JPA Provider). When I try to run a query, system provides me empty result list. But when I run SQL representation of same query (taken from logs), it runs fine and provides me correct results.

Can someone please help me in understanding what can be the possible issue here?

Comment: You can have JPA log its generated SQL to verify it is really running the same query. For Hibernate, you'd use `<property name = "hibernate.show_sql" value = "true" />`. Further, double/triple-check your app is querying the same DB as you're querying manually.

Comment: I have got the SQL String by setting hibernate.show_sql to true. Its running fine, giving me desired results.Also, I am quite sure that I am accessing same DB, because I am accessing database with my own user and I don't have my user created on any other DB :-)

Comment: I would go a step further : try setting up log4jdbc to see the 100% guaranteed correct SQL query with all parameters filled in. At the base it is going to be a plain JDBC query that is shot at the database, so it is impossible that you get different resultsets running the same query in two different environments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is probably with the parameter values. Do you use any parameter of a type that requires some inference from the provider (like an enum)? I've seen a complex JPQL query for which Hibernate 3.3 wasn't able to infer the type of an enum (Number or String) for an entity attribute because the entity attribute wasn't qualified with the entity alias in the query (entityAttribute instead of alias.entityAttribute). The enum was set as a parameter in its serialized form. Like @Gimby said, you can check the full Hibernate logs to see what are the real values set as parameters.

Comment: Thanks a lot, issue was with parameter values, my dropdown value had a space in it and due to which jquery was reading only half the value. I tried p6spy and got the answer. Thanks a ton again.